# How to run discord.py tasks within celery?

Tags: python, celery, discord.py, celery-task

I tried to create a celery task that returns the roles from my discord guild.: (proof of concept)

```py
...
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from celery import shared_task, Task
from discord.http import HTTPClient

class ChatTask(Task):
    _client = None

    @property
    def client(self) -> HTTPClient:
        if self._client is None:
            client = HTTPClient()
            result = async_to_sync(
                lambda: client.static_login(settings.BOT_TOKEN, bot=True)
            )()
            self._client = client
        return self._client


@shared_task(base=ChatTask, bind=True)
def get_roles(self):
    # Still testing!

    client: HTTPClient = self.client
    print(client)  # Seems to be fine: `<discord.http.HTTPClient object at 0x7fcc6728dbb0>`

    roles = async_to_sync(lambda: async_get_roles(client))()  # ERROR!: `RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')`
    print(roles)

    return roles
```

However I keep getting `RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')`.

*Comment: I do know that celery v5 will support async/await. But I do not want to wait until the release at the end of the year. ;)*

How can I fix this code to get rid of the error and actually get see the roles printed out to the console?

Comment: What did you decide to do?

Comment: I waited for the release of Celery 5 and will now try again. ^^

Comment: @Eraldo did you try again?